# VC++ Class Templates Implementing Function with typedef Type

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I've got some weird stuff going on at the moment. I'm trying to write a template class using the VC++ compiler.

Within my class i got a few typedef's for clarity. The actual implementation i have outside of my headerfile

```
template<typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,T>::type>
class Integer
{
public:
    typedef  T                      value_type;
    typedef  Integer < value_type > Self;
    typedef  Self&                  SelfReference;
    typedef  Self*                  SelfRawPointer;
    ...
public:
    SelfReference operator =(const SelfReference);
```

*.tcc - file:

```
...
template<typename T> Integer<T>::SelfReference Integer<T>::operator =(const 
Integer<T>::SelfReference rhs)
{
    return this->assign(rhs);
};
...
```

With the gcc in the past I haven't any problems by doing it this way BUT now on Windows the compiler is complaining that 'SelfReference':C2061: syntax error: identifier 'SelfReference'

I've got no clue what is wrong because with the gcc it worked in the past... did i missed something? The problem does not appear if i write the function inline. I'm now just curious why on windows I've got this kind of problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SelfReference` is a dependent type, therefore you need to use `typename`:

```
template <typename T>
typename Integer<T>::SelfReference Integer<T>::operator=(const typename Integer<T>::SelfReference rhs) { blah; }
```

To the right of the `Integer<T>::` you can also just use `SelfReference`, ie.

```
template <typename T>
typename Integer<T>::SelfReference Integer<T>::operator=(const SelfReference rhs) { blah; }
```

This was part of the reason for the `auto` return values in c++11, you can now write

```
template <typename T>
auto Integer<T>::operator=(const SelfReference rhs) -> SelfReference
{
     blah;
}
```